# Spring Eureka asks for username password authentication

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, microservices, netflix-eureka

```
    Using generated security password: f9268f9c-f2e6-4e53-a751-632a7005b807

2020-03-03 13:07:44.539  INFO 4824 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2a92f8c3, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@412324cd, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7cf2dd91, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@565adf96, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5b3457db, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@b1041fc, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@5e842f37, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@3e06198f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@574d3e0c, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@2b5beb1d, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@4d02763e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@b273c65, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1f6d3131, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1bf860da, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@11538685]
2020-03-03 13:07:44.612  WARN 4824 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : Unable to start LiveReload server
```

I didn't include spring security dependencies in POM file, but I'm seeing these lines in my console. Browser prompts for user name and password. How can I fix this?

Comment: run mvn dependency:tree and grep spring security to check if it present somehow

Comment: Oh, my bad. It has username user and the password as shown in the question, by default. Any way to override it?

Comment: Do you need security or not?

Comment: Is there any way to customize username and password? Yes I need security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Eureka server has username password authentication by default. Default username is user, and the password will be generated in the console!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so u should be verify or dependency in POM

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Is it included in Eureka package?

Comment: any way to change default credentials in Eureka?

Comment: make dependency as comment or delete in pom

Answer (score 0):

This can be set in application.yml (by profile).

```
spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: <your user>
      password: <your password>
```